# How can you get the shared NSColorPanel to an show alpha / opacity slider?

Tags: cocoa, opacity, alpha, nscolor, nscolorpanel

When you add an NSColorWell control, and click it, it displays the shared instance of NSColorPanel.
Unfortunately, by default it does not show the alpha / opacity slider.
This is also true when it is invoked from the default **MainMenu > Format > Font > Show Colors**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call the following line at any time in your app.

`[[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setShowsAlpha:YES];`

You can call it once in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` or you can easily tie it to a switch like an **NSButton** checkbox with a simple **IBAction** method like this:

```
- (IBAction)showAlphaSliderInColorPanel:(id)sender {
    if ([sender state] == NSOnState) {
        [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setShowsAlpha:YES];
    } else {
        [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setShowsAlpha:NO];
    }
}
```

Just connect that to the **Sent Actions** selector item in the Connections Inspector with for a button configured to have an on / off state.

The change will occur live as you click.

A great example of how awesome Cocoa is when you want it to be.